# What is the correct CSS file template for rails supposed to look like?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I'm doing a Rails tutorial for CSS and I've been instructed to create a shmoogle.css.scss file under app/assets/stylesheets/shmoogle.css.scss

Next to that file is the application.css file which looks like this:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include   
   all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, 
   vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a   
   relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the   
   bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any 
   styles
 * defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to 
   create a new
 * file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require_shmoogle
 */
```

Notice the second to last line where I require_shmoogle. Is this correct? Is it supposed to be commented out like this?

Comment: It should be `require shmoogle`, with a space in between.

Comment: Thanks for the reply vee. More specifically, within the commented area is it * require_shmoogle and then on the next line */ or is it outside of the commenting.

Comment: Correct, as mentioned in the comments, this is a manifest file that is used in asset pipelining.  You'd put all the requires following the suggested syntax within the comments and you'd put any custom css outside and below the comments.

Answer (score 1):

The `require_tree .` directive will include all css files in the current directory automatically, so you don't need a separate require statement for that specific file.

Custom requires come in handy when you need the files loaded in a certain order. For example:

```
*= require_self
*= require load_me_first
*= require load_me_next
*= require_tree ./subfolder_to_require_next
*= require_tree .
```

That code will include files in the order you specified and the final `require_tree .` will require everything else. If you don't want to include everything else, you can removed the `require_tree .` directive and require everything manually.

The comment nature of manifest files is expected. The special directives (starting with `*=`) cause special behavior in the asset pipeline. Any code written outside of the comment block will be interpreted as regular css code and included with the `require_self` directive.

You can read more about [Manifest Files and Directives](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives) in the [Assets Pipeline Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).

Answer (score 0):

It should be `require shmoogle`, but since you're already doing `require_tree .`, this statement is not necessary.  `require_tree` requires all stylesheets within the current directory recursively.

So update your `application.css` to include only:

```
*= require_tree .
*= require_self
```